# Matrix as the discretization of a function $u$ over a rectangle in 3D, how to fastly integrate along the axes?

Tags: matrix, numerical-integration, interpolation

I have a function $u$ from 3D to 1D approximated in a list `uu` and I want to calculate e.g.

$$\int_0^1 x\cdot u(x,y,z)dx$$

or

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 u(x,y,z)dxdydz$$

How do I do this fast?

A minimal example for my problem

```
(* domain*)
nn = 10.;
{xmin, ymin, zmin} = {0, 0, 0};
{xmax, ymax, zmax} = {1., 1., 1.};
xx = Subdivide[xmin, xmax, nn];
yy = Subdivide[ymin, ymax, nn];
zz = Subdivide[zmin, zmax, nn];
dx = xx[[2]] - xx[[1]];
(* create discrete uu *)
u[x_, y_, z_] := dx*(x + y + z)
uu = Table[u[x, y, z], {x, 0, nn}, {y, 0, nn}, {z, 0, nn}]
```

My search begun at [`ListIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FunctionApproximations/ref/ListIntegrate.html) and then I arrived at [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) which brought me to examples like

```
data = {1, 2, 3}
f = Interpolation[data[[1]], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 3}]
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, 3}]
Integrate[f[x], {x, 1, 3}]
```

But is this really the way to go?

EDIT: Since it seems to be the way I have an update with a question (for simplicity in 2D)

```
nn = 5.;
{xmin, ymin, zmin} = {0, 0, 0};
{xmax, ymax, zmax} = {1., 2., 1.};
xx = Subdivide[xmin, xmax, nn];
yy = Subdivide[ymin, ymax, nn];
zz = Subdivide[zmin, zmax, nn];
(* creaty step size *)
dx = xx[[2]] - xx[[1]];
(*create discrete uu and the x-y-grid *)
u[x_, y_] := (2 x + y)
uu = Table[u[x, y], {x, xx}, {y, yy}];
grid = Table[{xi, yi}, {xi, xx}, {yi, yy}];
uu // Dimensions;
f = Interpolation[{yy, uu[[1, ;;]]} // Transpose, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
NIntegrate[f[y] y, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Since I have my grid how do I assemble the combination of grid and uu as I did along the y-axis via

```
{yy, uu[[1, ;;]]} // Transpose
```

to fastly interpolate and integrate about both axes? Only idea I currently have is a table, since I have to do that every time step this is not smart I guess

Comment: `Interpolation` and `NIntegrate` would be my choice. Of course, you could write your own integration routine, but I trust the writers of `NIntegrate` more than myself.

Comment: thanks @MarcoB, I played a little bit around and I have no problem for an integral over one axis, however, I am confused doing it over both, can you help? Thus I edited the original post. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you know the x,y,z values of uu, or if they are even equidistant, Interpolation is well suited.

I changed your x,y,z defintions to avoid confusion.

```
nn = 10; 
{xmin, ymin, zmin} = {0, 0, 0}; 
{xmax, ymax, zmax} = {1, 1, 1}; 
{dx = (xmax - xmin)/nn, dy = (ymax - ymin)/nn, 
 dz = (zmax - zmin)/nn}; 
u[x_, y_, z_] = nn x + nn y + nn z; 
uu = Table[u[x, y, z], {x, xmin, xmax, dx}, 
   {y, ymin, ymax, dy}, {z, zmin, zmax, dz}];  

grid = Table[{x, y, z}, {x, xmin, xmax, dx}, {y, ymin, ymax, dy}, 
   {z, zmin, zmax, dz}];

mt = Flatten[MapThread[List, {grid, uu}, 3], 2]; 

ip = Interpolation[mt]

Manipulate[Plot3D[ip[x, y, z], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 30}], {z, 0, 1}]

nint[y_, z_] := NIntegrate[x*ip[x, y, z], {x, 0, 1}]

nint[.2, .4]

NIntegrate[ip[x, y, z], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]

(*   15.   *)

Integrate[ip[x, y, z], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

`Integrate`  is even much faster in this case.

Comment: Thanks alot for that clear code! have to play around with it.
happy new year @akku14